# match string to 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp' object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a string that I am trying to match to a 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp' object.

I have a pandas dataframe called `df` that looks as such with the objects in the `calendardate` columns defined as 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp' objects:

```
     ticker dimension calendardate
None                              
0      AMZN       MRY   2019-12-31
1      AMZN       MRY   2018-12-31
```

I also have a string defined as:

```
year = '2019-12-31'
```

When I have done  `year in df.calendardate` in produces `False`. I have also tried to convert it to a datetime object using:

```
datetime.strptime(year, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

But this once again gives `False` when tested if in.

Does anyone know how I would match this?

Thanks.

Comment: use `df['calendardate'])=pd.to_datetime(df['calendardate'])`

Comment: This has now changed to dtype hasn't it? This also still does not match and raises false after converting. @QuangHoang

Comment: There is also a mismatched bracket on the solution.

Comment: use `year in df.calendardate.values` (keep both as string or convert both to_datetime before).